# Can we write LaTeX inside python turtle graphics?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am looking for a way to write latex inside a figure drawn with turtle graphics. It doesn't accept it in the turtle.write() command. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Long time, no answer!